# Sencha touch - debug framework?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

How do I preview my sencha touch app in chrome in debug version so all my error coming from something in the sencha framework is not refering to the same huge line of code?

IE `sencha-touch-all.js:21`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build application use 'testing' target.

`sencha app build production` vs `sencha app build testing`

That if you build from command line. Not really sure how Architect handles that, but I'm pretty sure it calls same scripts/program underneath.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem, i dont know how to tell architect to do it in debut :(

Comment: Just open the app.html file in your browser... Architect doesn't bundle anything together until you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

To build the app locally using sencha command, type

**sencha app build testing**
This will create a minified file of app in the folder named testing

To run the app on browser, type
**Sencha web start**

A port number would be given where you can view in browser
Eg: http://localhost:1841/build/testing/App

where 1841 is the port number given to you when you run the above commands